# Is it possible to upgrade PowerShell 3 on Windows Server 2008 SP2 to higher versions?

Tags: windows, powershell, upgrade, windows-server-2008, windows-server

On a fully patched Windows Server 2008 SP2, I've upgraded Powershell 2 to 3. Is there no way to upgrade powershell to v5 or even v4?

Notes:
Powershell 2 to 3 installation done via: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595

Powershell 3 to 4 installation - fails :https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855

Comment: Does [installing Windows Management Framework 5.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.1/install-configure) work? I'm not sure that you need to install all the intermediate versions.

Comment: @BenN When it comes to upgrades, Windows 2008 Server R2 seems to be so much better off than Window 2008 Server. Upgrades meant for Windows 2008 Server R2 don't apply for Windows 2008 Server! Tried that, got "The update does not apply to your system."

Comment: Ah, my mistake; I had SP2 and R2 conflated. According to [this system requirements page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/windows-powershell-system-requirements?view=powershell-6), version 4.0 and higher need at least 2008 R2, [as does](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/01/10/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/) PowerShell Core (version 6), unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there no way to upgrade PowerShell to v5 or even v4?

No

> On a fully patched Windows Server 2008 SP2, I've upgraded Powershell 2 to 3.

In order to install PowerShell 4+, you must install Windows Management Framework 4.0, and neither Windows Management Framework 4.0 or Windows Management Framework 5.1 supports Windows Server 2008 SP2

[image]

Source: [WMF 5.1 Operating System Compatibility](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.1/compatibility)

> WMF 4.0 can only be installed on the following operating systems.
>
> - Windows 7 with Service Pack 1
> - **Windows Server 2008 R2** with Service Pack 1
> - Windows Server 2012

As for PowerShell Core, since it includes `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`, it also wouldn't support Windows Server 2008 SP2

> PowerShell Core (aka PowerShell 6) is officially supported on the following platforms:
>
> - **Windows Server 2008 R2**, 2012 R2, 2016

Source: [PowerShell Core 6.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/01/10/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/)